# Use Axios to get and save an Excel file

Tags: php, reactjs, axios

I am using react and axios to do a POST to a php service that will return a .xlsx file.  The .xlsx file is created properly on the server, but during transit back it gets corrupted, through the Chrome inspector the data seems to be getting converted to a string and many characters are getting changed as a result.  Is there a way to do this?  Things I have tried:

Headers on request

```
'Accept': 'application/octet-stream',
'responseType': 'blob',
```

With the response object

```
fileDownload(new Blob([response.data]), 'report.xlsx');
```

Alternatively with the response object

```
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
const link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = url;
link.setAttribute('download', 'file.xlsx');
link.click();
```

No matter what I try it seems to be getting corrupted.  On the server side I have the following PHP code:

```
$response = new Stream();
$response->setStream(fopen($tempFilePath, 'r'));
$response->setStatusCode(200);
$response->setStreamName($tempFilePath);
$responseHeaders = new Headers();
$responseHeaders->addHeaders(array(
    'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename='report.xlsx',
    'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream',
    'Content-Length' => filesize($tempFilePath),
    'Expires' => '@0', 
    'Cache-Control' => 'must-revalidate',
    'Pragma' => 'public'
));
$response->setHeaders($responseHeaders);
return $response;
```

Comment: @brocoli_rob had the solution below, it wasn't the Accept header so much as not using the axios.post helper and instead specifying everything into the normal axios call so you can separate header config from the responseType config item.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try removing `responseType` from the headers and add it directly into your options object that you pass into axios:

```
axios({
    method:'GET',
    url: '[your_url_to_get_file]',      
    responseType: 'blob', 
    headers: { your headers }
})
```

On top of that, I would try using `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` as your content-type, instead of `octect-stream`. I've never tried `octect-stream` but the one I mentioned has always worked for me with .xlsx files.

For reference about MIME types see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-2007-resource-kit/ee309278(v=office.12)).

Answer (score 7):

```
const axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');

const getXLS = () => {
    return axios.request({
    responseType: 'arraybuffer',
    url: 'https://drive.google.com/ft7P9FAQ/view?usp=sharing',
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'blob',
    },
  }).then((result) => {
      const outputFilename = 'xyzzzz.xls';
      fs.writeFileSync(outputFilename, result.data);
      return outputFilename;
    });
  }

  getXLS();
```

Comment: responseType: 'arraybuffer' did the trick for me, thanks!